# Object property returning undefined even when object is full. Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class of `ParametrosEscaner` like this:

```
export enum TiposPixel {
  BlancoNegro = 0,
  Grises,
  Color
};

export class ParametrosEscaner {
  tipoPixel: TiposPixel;
  resolucion: number;
  duplex: boolean;
  mostrarInterfaz: boolean;
};
```

And I have a component that receive an instance of this class using Input like this:

```
@Input() parametrosActuales: ParametrosEscaner = new ParametrosEscaner();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    if(this.parametrosActuales){
      console.log(this.parametrosActuales);
      this.interfaz = this.parametrosActuales.mostrarInterfaz;
      this.dobleCara = this.parametrosActuales.duplex;
      this.tipoSeleccionado = this.valoresEnum()[this.parametrosActuales.tipoPixel];
      this.resolucionSeleccionada = this.parametrosActuales.resolucion;
    }
  }
```

The thing is that even when my console log looks like this:

[image]

All the properties below are returning undefined... I just don´t understand whyyy

**EDIT**
The parent component sending the object looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._informacionPreferencias.preferenciasActuales.subscribe(pref => {
      this.preferenciasCargaUsuario = pref;
      debugger
      if(this.preferenciasCargaUsuario.ParametrosEscaner){
        this.parametrosEscaner = this.preferenciasCargaUsuario.ParametrosEscaner;
      }
    })
  }
```

`this.parametrosEscaner` is the object that the child receives

Comment: JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, e.g `duplex !== Duplex`

Comment: Of course. I didn't post it because the console log shows that is receiving the object just fine. But I'll post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're dealing with cases like `Alexey`(yurzui) mentioned.

Try:

```
this.interfaz = this.parametrosActuales.MostrarInterfaz;
this.dobleCara = this.parametrosActuales.Duplex;
this.tipoSeleccionado = this.valoresEnum()[this.parametrosActuales.TipoPixel];
this.resolucionSeleccionada = this.parametrosActuales.Resolucion;
```

Comment: this will cause an error because in the definition of the "ParametrosEscaner" class, the properties are all lowercase

Comment: post the `console.log` after `if(this.parametrosActuales)`

Comment: It's the one of the screenshot, the properties are not lowercase but I don't know really why because I'm using the same class in everything.

Comment: Right before passing it down to the child component where the log is occurring, can you log what you are passing down from the parent component?